# How to catch an error thrown by a third party library in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I'm using the [phpWhois](https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois) package in my Laravel application for performing whois lookup.

It's working fine except that for some websites that I enter, this error always occurs:

`'ErrorException in whois.gtld.godaddy.php line 50: Undefined index: owner'`

I googled it and found that this problem already has an open [issue](https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois/issues/6) on Github and also an existing [pull request](https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois/pull/21).

I don't want to copy and paste the suggested fix in the source code because it means I have to do it in every time I do `composer install`.

So I decided to catch the error instead but I don't know how.

I found a somewhat similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970479/catching-exceptions-from-library-using-laravel-5-2) here and tried the accepted solution but it is still throwing the exception.

Here's the existing code that I tried:

```
$whois = new \Whois();

try {
    $result = $whois->lookup($data['name']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return response()->json(['error' => $e]);
}
```

I would appreciate any comment/help.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try catching `ErrorException`

Comment: Thanks @CharlotteDunois. I have to put backslash though for it to work cause it won't if I don't.

Comment: Well yes, due to namespace.

Comment: Oh that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to catch an exception,You follow below mentioned programming style.

```
try {
    $whois = new \Whois();
    $result = $whois->lookup($data['name']);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    \var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

This above mentioned method work in almost all PHP frameworks.